# Extract 1 to 3 Digit Number from Parenthesis Within Text Field

Tags: formula

I have a field called 'Line Description' that contains a quantity in "( )" then a description of the item. Example: **(12) **ABC Extenders****. I am trying to extract the quantity in Number format. The quantity could be 0-999. I am using the formula below but it only returns (3) digit numbers, and anything that is a (1) or (2) digit number returns as blank. The field always starts with ( and follows directly by the number. Thanks in advance for you help!

```
VALUE(MID(LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION, FIND("(", LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION)+1,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
VALUE(MID(
LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION__c ,
FIND("(", LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION__c) + 1,
FIND(")", LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION__c) - FIND("(", LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION__c) - 1))
```